# How to search for a single letter and highlight all instaces of this

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I would like to know how to find all single letters in a passage that has been written in a text box and highlight/recolor them.

```
<textarea id="Input" cols="50" rows="5">
    Insert text to be modified here
</textarea>
```

```js
$("#singles").click(function() {
    $(function() {
        var foundin = $('*:contains("")');
    });
```

This is the sort of thing I have tried but I don't know

- How to return true for this statement/ how to get it to execute the
  code afterwards
- What is used as a space i.e `&nbsp;*&nbsp;` looks as
  though it would work :/

Comment: A little heads up, I placed & n b s p ; near the bottom of my question but it made the spaces anyway xD silly stack overflow! But it would've said &nbsp with a semi-colon afterwards to illustrate a non-breaking space :)

Comment: FYI You can't add styling to individual characters within a `textarea` element, only the text as a whole. If you need this behaviour you would need to use another solution, such as a contenteditable div.

Comment: Thanks :) I will look at that for holding my contents :)